# Fortnightly Topic Challenge Automation on Puzzling.SE

Tags: app, api

Used for (meta.)puzzling.stackexchange - Creates & edits the corresponding meta posts with information from the main and meta site. E.g. creating a post for the new challenge every 2 weeks and updating the current post with new entries.

"Fortnightly Topic Challenges" are themed challenges posted every 2 weeks. This was done manually before. See https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/fortnightly-topic-challenges-threrun-topic-suggestions

**2023/04/25**

The bot is currently being used for [Monthly Topic Challenges](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/monthly-topic-challenges-topic-suggestions) over at PSE, and has been for some time now. It creates the topics and automatically updates the list of entries. [Example](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7464/monthly-topic-challenge-9-game-quiz-shows)